# How to Add the DropDownList in GridView with item selection and textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in asp.net development

I have created a project its working fine but i want to select the Designation from drop down but want to store the id of the designation instead of the designation
Here is my Asp.net Code for my Project

```
protected void BindData()
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conn.Open();

            string cmdstr = "Select * from EmployeeDetails";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(ds);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
      }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
            {

                TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");

                TextBox txtAddName = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddName");

                DropDownList ddlDesignation = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlDesignation");

                TextBox txtAddCity = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCity");

                TextBox txtAddCountry = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCountry");


                conn.Open();

                string cmdstr = "insert into EmployeeDetails(empid,name,designation,city,country) values(@empid,@name,@designation,@city,@country)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtAddEmpID.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAddName.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", ddlDesignation.SelectedItem.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtAddCity.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txtAddCountry.Text);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

                BindData();

            }

        }
        protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                DropDownList ddlDesignation = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDesignation");

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                conn.Open();

                string cmdstr = "Select * from Designation";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);

                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                adp.Fill(ds);

                ddlDesignation.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                ddlDesignation.DataTextField = "designation";


                ddlDesignation.DataValueField = "id";

                ddlDesignation.DataBind();

                ddlDesignation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));


                this.TextBox1.Text = ddlDesignation.SelectedItem.ToString();


                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```

and also this is my aspx.cs code for project

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound"
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

     <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEmpID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "designation") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesignation" runat="server" >

                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "country") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">

                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="ADD" Text="Add" Width="100px"></asp:LinkButton>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line is unnecessary by the way since you use `SELECT` statement.

Comment: So what issue are you facing?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl i want to get design id in TextBox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get value from `SelectedValue` property of dropdwon.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", ddlDesignation.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Ahmed Thanks for Your Response dear now how can i show empty gridview on every page load?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlDesignation");
var strDesigId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = strDesigId;
```